# Laravel / Lumen API, Parse error in vendor folder

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

As I am working in laravel / lumen API, it is throwing error which is as below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/battlegame/new_api/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php
>   on line 156

Comment: are u getting this from new repository laravel or old

Comment: new repository @sidheart

Comment: can i see your web.php and api.php from routes

Comment: i can't understand this code is not readable so please edit your question and post this as code

Comment: `$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
$router->get('user[/{name}]', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->post('login', 'MemberController@authenticate');
    $router->post('register', 'MemberController@createMemeber');
    $router->post('forgot_password', 'MemberController@forgotpassword');
//    $router->get('customer_support', 'MemberController@customerSupport');
});` @sidheart